# ¿como puedo hacer que la card donde este el pokemon al usar por ejemplo hover tome el color del tipo que es?

Tags: html, css

> Hola mucho gusto soy nuevo en la programcion llevo 2 meses aprendiendo de ello espero puedan ayudarme con esta duda
> Abajo tienen todo el código para ello pero las imágenes no las puse ya que son descargadas y es mi primera vez preguntando en stack overflow, asi que no se como añadirlas
> Me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de usar el root para ello si ese es el caso de que forma podría hacerlo o con javascript en tal caso si me podrían decir como hacerlo ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento de Js como tal

```css
:root {
      --clr-black: #1c1c1c;
      --clr-gray: #ececec;
      --clr-white: #f7f7f7;
      --type-normal: #a8a878;
      --type-fire: #f05030;
      --type-water: #3899f8;
      --type-grass: #78c850;
      --type-electric: #f8d030;
      --type-ice: #58c8e0;
      --type-fighting: #a05038;
      --type-poison: #b058a0;
      --type-ground: #e9d6a4;
      --type-flying: #98a8f0;
      --type-psychic: #f870a0;
      --type-bug: #a8b820;
      --type-rock: #b8a058;
      --type-ghost: #6060b0;
      --type-dark: #7a5848;
      --type-dragon: #7860e0;
      --type-steel: #a8a8c0;
      --type-fairy: #e79fe7;
    }

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: var(--clr-black);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(Img/Fondo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  padding-block: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem -1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img {
  width: 20pc;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.7rem;
}

.btn-header {
  background-color: var(--clr-gray);
  padding: 0.7rem;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn-header:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

main {
  padding: 2rem;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pokemon-todos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 470px) {
  .pokemon-todos {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .pokemon-todos {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.pokemon {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--clr-white);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem -1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding-block: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.pokemon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.pokemon-imagen {
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pokemon-imagen img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 6rem;
}

.pokemon-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.nombre-contenedor {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pokemon-id {
  background-color: var(--clr-gray);
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.pokemon-nombre {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.pokemon-tipos {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tipo {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 100vh;
}

.pokemon-stats {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.stat {
  background-color: var(--clr-gray);
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 100vh;
}

.normal {
  background-color: var(--type-normal);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.fire {
  background-color: var(--type-fire);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.water {
  background-color: var(--type-water);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.grass {
  background-color: var(--type-grass);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.electric {
  background-color: var(--type-electric);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.ice {
  background-color: var(--type-ice);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.fighting {
  background-color: var(--type-fighting);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.poison {
  background-color: var(--type-poison);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.ground {
  background-color: var(--type-ground);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.flying {
  background-color: var(--type-flying);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.psychic {
  background-color: var(--type-psychic);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.bug {
  background-color: var(--type-bug);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.rock {
  background-color: var(--type-rock);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.ghost {
  background-color: var(--type-ghost);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.dark {
  background-color: var(--type-dark);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.dragon {
  background-color: var(--type-dragon);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.steel {
  background-color: var(--type-steel);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}

.fairy {
  background-color: var(--type-fairy);
  color: var(--clr-black);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--CSS Style Basic-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Pokedex</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="Img/Pokedex.png" alt="Logo Pokedex">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header" id="ver-todos">Ver todos</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header normal" id="normal">Normal</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header fire" id="fire">Fire</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header water" id="water">Water</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header grass" id="grass">Grass</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header electric" id="electric">Electric</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header ice" id="ice">Ice</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header fighting" id="fighting">Fighting</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header poison" id="poison">Poison</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header ground" id="ground">Ground</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header flying" id="flying">Flying</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header psychic" id="psychic">Psychic</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header bug" id="bug">Bug</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header rock" id="rock">Rock</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header ghost" id="ghost">Ghost</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header dark" id="dark">Dark</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header dragon" id="dragon">Dragon</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header steel" id="steel">Steel</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button class="btn btn-header fairy" id="fairy">Fairy</button></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>

    <div id="todos">
      <div class="pokemon-todos" id="listaPokemon">
        <div class="pokemon">
          <div class="pokemon-imagen">
            <img src="" alt="Bulbasaur">
          </div>
          <div class="pokemon-info">
            <div class="nombre-contenedor">
              <p class="pokemon-id">#0001</p>
              <h2 class="pokemon-nombre">Bulbasaur</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-tipos">
              <p class="grass tipo">grass</p>
              <p class="poison tipo">POISON</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-stats">
              <p class="stat">0,7m</p>
              <p class="stat">6,9kg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pokemon">
          <div class="pokemon-imagen">
            <img src="" alt="Ivysaur">
          </div>
          <div class="pokemon-info">
            <div class="nombre-contenedor">
              <p class="pokemon-id">#0002</p>
              <h2 class="pokemon-nombre">Ivysaur</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-tipos">
              <p class="grass tipo">grass</p>
              <p class="poison tipo">POISON</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-stats">
              <p class="stat">1,0m</p>
              <p class="stat">13,0kg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pokemon">
          <div class="pokemon-imagen">
            <img src="" alt="Venusaur">
          </div>
          <div class="pokemon-info">
            <div class="nombre-contenedor">
              <p class="pokemon-id">#0003</p>
              <h2 class="pokemon-nombre">Venusaur</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-tipos">
              <p class="grass tipo">grass</p>
              <p class="poison tipo">POISON</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-stats">
              <p class="stat">2,0m</p>
              <p class="stat">100,0kg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pokemon">
          <div class="pokemon-imagen">
            <img src="" alt="Charmander">
          </div>
          <div class="pokemon-info">
            <div class="nombre-contenedor">
              <p class="pokemon-id">#0004</p>
              <h2 class="pokemon-nombre">Charmander</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-tipos">
              <p class="fire tipo">FIRE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-stats">
              <p class="stat">0,6m</p>
              <p class="stat">8,5kg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pokemon">
          <div class="pokemon-imagen">
            <img src="" alt="Charmeleon">
          </div>
          <div class="pokemon-info">
            <div class="nombre-contenedor">
              <p class="pokemon-id">#0005</p>
              <h2 class="pokemon-nombre">Charmeleon</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-tipos">
              <p class="fire tipo">FIRE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-stats">
              <p class="stat">1,9m</p>
              <p class="stat">19,0kg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pokemon">
          <div class="pokemon-imagen">
            <img src="" alt="Charizard">
          </div>
          <div class="pokemon-info">
            <div class="nombre-contenedor">
              <p class="pokemon-id">#0006</p>
              <h2 class="pokemon-nombre">Charizard</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-tipos">
              <p class="fire tipo">FIRE</p>
              <p class="flying tipo">FLYING</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pokemon-stats">
              <p class="stat">1,7m</p>
              <p class="stat">90,5kg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ahora, en todo ese codigo, que partes son las que tienen problemas???